# com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: TIMESTAMP_FILES\TS_FILE.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3

I am trying to write to my file in the s3 bucket at TIMESTAMP_FILES/TS_FILE.txt

Here is my code :

```
 private static final String FOLDER_NAME = "TIMESTAMP_FILES/";

 public void sendToOSS(String fileName, String bucketName) {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsId, awsKey);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(s3host, "us-east-1"))
            .build();
    if (s3Client.doesBucketExist(bucketName)) {
        s3Client.putObject(bucketName, FOLDER_NAME + fileName, new File(folderName + File.separator + fileName));
    }
 }
```

I am calling this function using :

```
 fileTransferToS3.sendToOSS(keyName,bucketName); //keyName = TS_FILE.txt
```

While debugging, I got the cause :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:TIMESTAMP_FILES\TS_FILE.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```